# Bootstrap is not resposive in mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The following code have 6 `div` blocks.

6 blocks supposed to align horizontally in large screen

3 blocks supposed to align horizontally in mobile screen (3 div block *2 row )

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class=" col-sm-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class=" col-sm-2">
      3
    </div>
    <div class=" col-sm-2">
     4
    </div>
    
    <div class=" col-sm-2">
      5
    </div>
    <div class=" col-sm-2">
     6
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The above code block inside basic bootstrap5 template.
But I am not getting desired result, instead all `div` elements stack in column in mobile screen
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class should be `"col-4 col-lg-2"`

For mobile screens, the screen width is `<576px` for that the col class will be `"col-*"` and fr large screen its `"col-lg-*"`

Refer [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you've only defined what would happen to your columns starting from the `small` property (the `sm` in `col-sm-2` means `small`) and in bootstrap 4: `col-sm` means `>=576px`, [refer to this link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_xsmall.asp)

So what you need to do is remove the `sm` from `col-sm-2` and if you need to change your columns for the bigger width then you would set their values like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
     4
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
     6
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It'll be `col-4 col-lg-2` and not `col-2 col-lg-4`. OP needs 3 columns on `sm` and 6 on `lg`.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the correct answer and the time dedicated